# removed object not disappearing and 2025 error, as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a turn based strategy game on a grid map. To move your characcters around, I'm using click detection to see which direction the player intends. The code I'm using removes the old object, I presume, the adds the new one in one space to the right. The problem is that when I remove my object the image of the object remains where it began, while the actual objects reappears in the correct position. Then, when I try again, flash throws a 2025 error. Here is the code.

```
if(s == 0){
        sarray[s] = [main, maincharacter, mc, 3]
        enemyiden = "gwr"
    }
    else if(s == 1){
        sarray[s] = [mcaxe, mainaxe, mcaxeman, 3]
        enemyiden = "gar"
    }
    else if(s == 2){
        sarray[s] = [mchorse, maincav, mccavalry, 5]
        enemyiden = "gcr"
    }
    for(var g:int = 0; g < tilepositions.xcoords.length; g++){
        if(tilepositions.xcoords[g] == Allies[s][0] - 12.5){
            break
        }
    }
    for(var h:int = 0; h < tilepositions.ycoords.length; h++){
        if(tilepositions.ycoords[h] == Allies[s][1] - 12.5){
            break
        }
    }
if(mouseX < Allies[s][0] && Math.abs(mouseX - Allies[s][0]) < 37.5 && Math.abs(mouseY - Allies[s][1]) < 12.5 ){
        trace("test1")
        this.removeChild(sarray[s][0])
        sarray[s][0] = new Sprite
        this.addChild(sarray[s][0])
        trace(this.contains(sarray[s][0]))
        sarray[s][1] = new sarray[s][2]
        sarray[s][0].addChild(sarray[s][1])
        sarray[s][0].x = tilepositions.xcoords[g-1]
        sarray[s][0].y = tilepositions.ycoords[h]
        Allies[s][0] = sarray[s][0].x + 12.5
        movecurr[s] += 1
        break
}
```

"s" is a for loop variable that counts upward. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within this line: `this.removeChild(sarray[s][0])`. And the error says it all: *ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller*, which means that `sarray[s][0]` is not child of `this`. There's no magical way to tell you why, as we don't know, but if you fix this the problem will be resolved :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would, however like more help. I have somewhat solved the problem, as the error no longer occurs, however ,the original object still does not disappear. If more of the source would be helpful, I am happy to post it.

Comment: You need to understand the basic principles of AS3. I cannot help you with a magic stick, especially when you have a whole project that needs debugging. You just need to remove the exact same object that you've added. It's good to use `contains` before `removeChild`, as well as trace all children if you think there are some leftovers (use `for (var i:uint = 0; i < object.numChildren; i++)`). Also **add names** to that objects so you can see which one is left behind!

Comment: contains is actually a misleading method as it would not tell you if the calling object contains directly the checked object. It will tell you that somewhere in the calling object display list it has found the object which doesn't mean the calling object is the direct parent.